# How to pass path of the filename

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, file

I am asking a very basic question but I am confused about it.

```
filepath = os.path.join(dir_path, 'filename.txt')
f1 = open(r'E:/pjt/filename.txt', 'w+')
```

I am trying to pass the location of filename.txt to the second step. Can anybody teach me how to do it? I tried using `+filepath+` but I could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filepath` is already a path to the file - just use it:

```
filepath = os.path.join(dir_path, 'filename.txt')
f1 = open(filepath, 'w+')
# Here ---^
```

Comment: That's only relevant for **literals** - `r'` stands for "raw string" - it instructs python to treat the text of the string "as-is", and not use `\` as an escape character. See https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet to get the current directory of the file, then use it for join or other commands.

```
import os
_cur_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```